# How to delete an entry in a table along with its data in another table?

Tags: laravel

I have a table `cars` with attributes: `id`, `name`. I also have another table `specs` with `id`, `car_id`, `name`. This tables are related with one to many relations from the Models. I also have set up the foreign keys in.

I have a controller `manageData` where i have a function `insertCar` which i use to insert data and update both tables. I wan to create another function `deleteCar` from where i can delete the car along with its specs from the other table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `onDelete()` method in migration when defining foreign key:

```
$table->foreign('car_id')->references('id')->on('cars')->onDelete('cascade');
```

In this case when you'll delete a car record, related data will be automatically deleted from another table.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#foreign-key-constraints